# Can we have an "automatic indentation" button for phones?

Tags: feature-request, editor, mobile-web

It is really hard to indent code with more than 100 lines using a phone. It was a nightmare to me indenting the code using the space bar on the phone. Since you can't see lines on the top, you can't indent without scrolling up and down. Even if you indent correctly, it gives errors that it is not indented properly. It is very hard to count the number of spaces on a phone. Wouldn't it be convenient if there was an automatic indentation button, at least when you are not using indent sensitive languages like Python?

**Edit**

I was trying to edit the code in the question (to add few lines), but when I copied and pasted, all the indentation was gone.

Comment: Don't post 100 lines of code from a device where you don't have an editor or IDE that lets you format and run that code.

Comment: There's already a button for "automatic indentation": Highlight the code and press the button with the curly brackets `{ }` or press Ctrl-K. But as Bill mentions, use the best device/environment for the task at hand.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The toolbar is not available in the mobile view, except for an *Add picture* button.

Comment: @BilltheLizard actually I needed to edit the code in the question, when u copy and past the code from the question, all the indentation is gone ,

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it is not working on mobile devices as expected,

Comment: @Stijn Ah, I never use the mobile view, nor the app, for anything but basic comments and moderation. I guess I always wait to use a desktop for anything more complicated...

Comment: It amazes and slightly horrifies me that people try to make complicated edits to code on a phone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better editor (with better support for editing *code*) **would** be really nice. [Here's a Chrome extension that'll give you one...](https://stackapps.com/questions/6926/stack-exchange-improvements-sticky-top-bar-new-text-editor-and-more)

But... Please don't try posting large amounts of code from your phone. Even if you manage to do it without screwing up the formatting, there's very little chance you're actually *testing* the code on your phone or able to respond to suggestions for improvement; unless you're able to set up an environment where such things are possible (and thus you have a full-featured editor that'll handle indentation and the like for you), it's best to wait.

Comment: When u copy and paste the code from the question in order to edit it , all the indentation is gone , in fact I needed to add few lines and had to indent all the code ,

Comment: If you copy and paste from within the editor, the indentation is preserved, unless for some reason, your phone's operating system is stripping out leading whitespace when you copy things onto the clipboard? @lasan